# BigQuery equivalent for CONCAT_WS

Tags: sql, string, google-bigquery

What is the CONCAT_WS equivalent in BigQuery

Comment: Please help us know what CONCAT_WS does with example.

Comment: do you have some example data?  Specifically looking for how the data is structured that you are trying to concatenate, across a single row or multiple

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `concat_ws` means "concatenat with separator" , e.g.
`concat_ws( 'string1', 'string2', 'string3', ';' ) returns 'string1;string2;string3'`

Answer (score 1):

There is no exact string function available but you can use CONCAT as::

```
SELECT CONCAT('T.P.', ' ', 'Bar') as author;

+---------------------+
| author              |
+---------------------+
| T.P. Bar            |
+---------------------+
```

[more references](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#concat)

Answer (score 0):

[ARRAY_TO_STRING](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#array_to_string) does the trick in BigQuery.

The syntax is:

```
SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING(['foo', 'bar'], '#');
```

This produces the string 'foo#bar'

It ignores NULL values in the same way like Hive CONCAT_WS, i.e., it doesn't introduce duplicate separators:

```
SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING(['foo', NULL, 'bar'], '#');
```

This still produces the same string 'foo#bar'